# Fetch data with sum for last 12 month

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate report from database and I have problem with query. So:

I have three tables:

- `orders` (with `order_id, order_date, order_total, clients.client_id, shippings.ship_id`)
- `clients`
- `shippings`

Now I want to `fetch orders.*, clients.*, shippings.*` as one row
which I can achieve with left join like:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM orders AS a
LEFT JOIN clients AS b ON a.client_id = b.client_id
LEFT JOIN shippings AS c ON a.ship_id = c.ship_id
```

But for that row I want to include 12 columns (i.e. month01, month02, month03) which will have sum of `orders.order_total` for last 12 months assigned by `orders.order_date`.

I can achieve this via getting all [order, client, shipping] rows and then individually for each row by querying this:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(order_date, \'%m.%Y\') AS order_month,
    SUM(order_total) AS order_sum 
FROM 
    orders
WHERE 
    client_id = '.intval($clientID).'
    AND ship_id = '.intval($shipID).'
    AND order_date >= DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), \'%Y-%m-01\'), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY 
    order_month;
```

But this gives me another 12 rows of data with two columns: `order_month` and `order_sum`

Is there a way to fetch all of this in one query with months included in one row?

SAMPLE DATA (create for last 4 months here):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/139c6

Comment: Please remove GROUP BY order_month;  This will create problem.

Comment: I have the feeling you want a pivot by month with conditional aggregation.  Could you include some sample data?

Comment: DivyeshPatoriya - removing GROUP BY still gives me months in rows instead of columns with correct values. Here is the problem - i don't know how to achieve that



@TimBiegeleisen - I'm preparing fiddle, give me sec

Answer (score 1):

I have written you the SQL, but I can't test it. So I hope it works. It has one column more then you want (mmonth): month from start

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date, \'%m.%Y\') AS order_month,
  SUM(order_total) AS order_sum,
  @mdiff := (PERIOD_DIFF( DATE(order_date) , DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH )) / 100),
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  0 , order_total, 0)) month_01,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  1 , order_total, 0)) month_02,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  2 , order_total, 0)) month_03,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  3 , order_total, 0)) month_04,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  4 , order_total, 0)) month_05,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  5 , order_total, 0)) month_06,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  6 , order_total, 0)) month_07,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  7 , order_total, 0)) month_08,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  8 , order_total, 0)) month_09,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff =  9 , order_total, 0)) month_10,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff = 10 , order_total, 0)) month_11,
  SUM(IF(@mdiff = 11 , order_total, 0)) month_12
FROM orders
WHERE client_id = '.intval($clientID).'
AND ship_id = '.intval($shipID).'
AND order_date >= DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), \'%Y-%m-01\'), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY order_month;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'month_01, SUM(IF(@mdiff = 1 , order_total, 0) month_02, SUM(IF(@mdiff = 2 ' at line 4

Comment: Anyway here i need to include `client_id` and `ship_id`, but I want this result to be joined to the main result :/

Comment: @rgwsk65 - mhhh, not my day missing the one  ) in each line

Comment: Yeah, I checked it, but it gaves me only `0` in each month

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/139c6/12

Comment: I fixed it to work, thanks Bernd. Now i have something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/139c6/19 . Now I must just join that table to the first table. If I do this, I'll post the answer.

Comment: I fixed @mdiff to be correct and sums in months are "incomplete" :/

Comment: whats wrong ? do you want to have 1 row ? i have looked in sqlfiddle. i am offline 2 hours, but i can show later